# reference on TikZ and Beamer overlay specifications

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I read that: **TikZ commands also accept Beamer overlay
specifications, such as \draw<2-> (A) to (B);** but I can not find any reference for it on the TikZ/PGF 3.0 manual. When I search for overlays in the +1000 page manual I got some other unrelated topic. Google and Bing were not helpful either. Please, could anyone indicate **where I can find more details about overlay specifications in TikZ commands?** If not in the manual, perhaps another reference then?

Comment: Perhaps you find something by looking throught http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf+beamer+overlays

Comment: @samcater thanks but off course I searched here before posting the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no mention of this fact neither in the `PGF/TikZ` nor in the `beamer` manuals (at least I couldn't find any reference).

The place where all the magic happens is the file `tikz.code.tex` (located in `.../tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/`) which contains the definitions for the front-end layer; there you'll find (lines 1833-1836):

```
\def\tikz@path@overlay#1{%
  \let\tikz@signal@path=\tikz@signal@path% for detection at begin of matrix cell
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar<{\tikz@path@overlayed{#1}}{\path #1}}
\def\tikz@path@overlayed#1<#2>{\path<#2> #1}
```

And also, some lines below (1938-1950), for filling/drawing:

```
\def\tikz@swap@args[#1]<#2>{\tikz@command@path<#2>[#1]}

\def\tikz@doopt{%
  \let\tikz@next=\tikz@eargnormalsemicolon%
  \ifnum\the\catcode`\;=\active\relax%
    \let\tikz@next=\tikz@eargactivesemicolon%
  \fi%
  \tikz@next}
\long\def\tikz@eargnormalsemicolon<#1>#2;{\alt<#1>{\tikz@@command@path#2;}{\tikz@path@do@at@end}}
{
  \catcode`\;=\active
  \long\global\def\tikz@eargactivesemicolon<#1>#2;{\alt<#1>{\tikz@@command@path#2;}{\tikz@path@do@at@end}}
}
```

Although the code is not documented, you can see (specially the last line of the first code snippet), that `\path` is made overlay-aware (in the `beamer` sense) there, so basically anything that is a path (`\node`, `\draw`, `\fill`, etc.) is overlay-aware.

As **Sean Allred** mentions in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174226/reference-on-tikz-and-beamer-overlay-specifications#comment407233_175100), it's also worth mentioning the [`aobs-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) package which de­fines aux­il­iary TikZ styles use­ful for over­lay­ing pic­ture elements in `beamer`.

A simple example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tikz\draw[thick, alt=<2-4>{blue}{red}] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Another interesting example of the use of this library can be found in [`my answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175279/3954) to [How can I make Beamer overlays with TikZ node attributes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175228/3954).

Comment: I would also add that you can `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}` and use its `alt` key in styles, as in `\tikz\draw[thick, alt=<2-4>{blue}{red}] (0,0) -- (1,1);`.  More in `texdoc aobs`.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, that's a useful addition. I've updated my answer incorporating your suggestion. Thanks.