# Latex beamer: make plots show sequentially

Tags: beamer

I am trying to insert image shown below in the link in Latex Beamer. Just like using PowerPoint, I want show A first and then go to B and then C.
I am wondering how to do this in Beamer?

[image: This is the plots I want to shown][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBDxY.png)

Comment: Are you generating the boxes with TikZ (or something else) or are you *just* inserting the image. A possible answer depends on where you start from.

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node

Answer (score 4):

If you want to draw your figure with `TiKZ`, it's possible to use the undocumented beamer overlay specifications detailed in [reference on TikZ and Beamer overlay specifications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174226/reference-on-tikz-and-beamer-overlay-specifications)

Your figure could be drawn with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={fill=blue!40, draw=blue!70!black, thick, minimum width = 2cm}]

\node<1-> (a) {A};
\node<2->[right=of a] (b) {B};
\node<3->[right=of b] (c) {C};
\draw<2->[->, thick,blue!70!black] (a)--(b);
\draw<3->[->, thick,blue!70!black] (b)--(c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]